# Django: Sort object by string attribute non-alphabetically

Tags: python, django, object

So, in my Django.models I have a class as the following:

```
class Basicorderbook(models.Model):
    ordernumber = models.ForeignKey('Idbook', db_column='OrderNumber', related_name='BasicOrder_IDNumber', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    username = models.ForeignKey('Userbook', db_column='Username', to_field='username', related_name='BasicOrder_Username')  # Field name made lowercase.
    price = models.FloatField(db_column='Price')  # Field name made lowercase.
    volume = models.FloatField(db_column='Volume')  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.ordernumber.idnumber)

...
```

and a view as the following to return an object containing multiple "Basic Orders":

```
class BuyOrdersView(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Basicorderbook
    template_name = 'Blank.html'
    context_object_name = 'buy_order_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Returns the 5 most viable buy orders
        """
        base_buy_order_list = models.Basicorderbook.objects.using('exchange').filter(
            action = 'Buy',
            #price > 520,
            #active = 1
            )
        volume_buy_order_list = base_buy_order_list.order_by('-volume')
        #This line here in question (I know this won't work, it's just an example)
        type_buy_order_list = volume_buy_order_list.order_by('Limit' in 'type')
        price_buy_orders = type_buy_order_list.order_by('-price')
        buy_order_list = price_buy_orders[:15]
        return buy_order_list
```

The "type" attribute of the object can be either "Limit", "Liquid", or "Conditional"

As shown, the problem lies in how I intend to sort the order object. I want to make it so that it is ordered with the following hierarchy:

1. Highest price first
2. If price is the same, have orders with "conditional" type first, then "limit", then "liquid"
3. If an order's price and type are the same, have orders sorted by volume

The numerical values (Price, Volume) are easily sortable by the handy order_by function, but when it comes to the string attributes I've come to a stop. It's not even an alphabetical order, so I can't do it that way. I see a few options that are simply annoying and inefficient workarounds:

1. Use a for loop to take each object and append into a list based on their string attribute
2. Create another attribute, "TypePriority", which I assign a numerical value (1, 2, 3) based on its priority in regards to the order type

So my TLDR question is, is there a way to sort objects based on a string value attribute in a non-alphabetic order? Also, will my object maintain it's sorting hierarchy with my current model, or should I join the order_by statements in a different way (Not sure if sorting by a certain attribute will "unsort" the new object I just created).

Note: the "_list" suffix is only for clarity, I know it's not a list :)

UPDATE: My current implementation that works is my workaround #1 example, but I'm wondering if there's way to sort it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update, but it turns out that there is no way to reorder the object as I wanted. I ended up doing the other reorganizations (by price, volume, etc.), but had to create a new list and check for the "type" attribute and sort them as such. It ended up looking like:

```
type_buy_order_list = []
for order in volume_buy_order_list:
    if order[3] == "limit":
        type_buy_order_list.append(order)
    if order[3] == "liquid":
        type_buy_order_list.append(order)
    if order[3] == "conditional":
        type_buy_order_list.append(order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your text 'conditional' < 'limit' < 'liquid' so sorting on this should work.
Can you just do a three-way sort such as ('-price', 'type', 'volume') ?
Off course this assumes that the sort is not case sensitive or the input is modified at some point

D.

Comment: Alright, so the sorting is possible. That's 1 part; The other is how I might sort the "type" part. The "liquid", "limit", and "conditional" values are strings within the "order" object, which is within the "..._list" object. I'm not sure if there's a function for such a reordering method, or whether I need to figure out a more abstract approach. Syntax/example and link to the relative documentation (If applicable) would be A+